# Can the feminine pronouns be gender-neutral?

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-gender, singular-they, gender-neutral

I know this sounds weird but I've been noticing a lot of texts on the Internet like this one:

"Any citizen is concerned with her well-being ...". The word in question is "her". To me it seems like in this case "her" is being used as a gender-neutral pronoun. Is this really the case or is it something else?

Comment: Have you checked the Wikipedia article on gender neutral pronouns? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_neutral_pronouns

Comment: No I have not. Don't tase me bro!

Comment: Not tasing; just encouraging due diligence.

Comment: the simple answer is "yes, this is a common trend in English today"

Answer (score 5):

It is indeed an attempt to use "her" as a gender-neutral pronoun. It is likely that the author is trying to even out gender bias, by using "his" and "her" with equal frequency, when a gender-neutral sentence is desired.

It is a problem in English. "Their" is not really a satisfactory word for the purpose, yet the standard "his", used universally, gives a huge male bias to English writing.

Comment: To be fair, the more common use of "his" in linguistics is unrelated to social questions of gender equality.

Comment: Try telling Andrea Dworkin that ;)

Comment: Ok, I understand now. I asked because I found it confusing.

Comment: @Slim: why do you suggest that "their" is not satisfactory?

Comment: To jump on, why is 'their' not satisfactory? I"d really like to know the justification.

Comment: @tenfour because traditionally "their" is only used in the plural. It is a relatively recent development to attempt to also use it as a singular gender-neutral pronoun (because English doesn't have one), and it sounds unnatural to many people.

Comment: @tenfour,Mitch: Most likely many of the people who object to "his" will be the same people as don't like "their" - a nitpicker is a nitpicker, regardless of which particular usage he/she/they happen to be banging on about at any given moment.

Comment: @slim: "They" sounds unnatural to non-native English speakers. BTW, English isn't the only language lacking a singular gender-neutral pronoun when referring to people, but it's the language having the most satisfactory solution of "they".

Comment: @slim: Singular "they" has been around a long time. Objecting to it now is almost as odd as objecting to singular "you" and insisting on "thou".

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 it was considered novel enough to be a debating point when I studied Natural Language Processing ~10 years ago. It usually feels forced to me; as if the writer wrote "his" then substituted "their" as a correction.

Comment: @slim I am pretty sure an extremely small number of native English speakers would agree with that. "They" is appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 1):

There is a trend to mix up the gender of pronouns, alternating between masculine and feminine, rather than to use the awkward gender-neutral formulations like "his or her", or, worse still, "s/he".

Comment: Isn't it more usual to use "they" instead? To my ears it sounds a lot less awkward than using alternatively "he" and "she".

Comment: Or the even worse "s/h/it". :-)

Comment: @Irene: It is, and doing so has a long and respectable tradition.

Comment: @Irene If a person does that, they are wrong.