# Why are "player", "researcher" and "designer" referred to by a feminine gender specific pronoun?

Tags: grammatical-gender, personal-pronouns, singular-they

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can the feminine pronouns be gender-neutral?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51948/can-the-feminine-pronouns-be-gender-neutral)
>   [Reason for the current trend to use "she" as the gender-neutral pronoun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28508/reason-for-the-current-trend-to-use-she-as-the-gender-neutral-pronoun)

In a lot of academic literature that I'm reading for school, I find constructions similar to this:

> "Thus enters the question of values in research activities as well, and
>   a fuller discussion of what is good – that is, what values should
>   guide the researcher in **her studies** and interventions – is required.
>   (Ravn 1991: 112)"

I'm wondering as to what the gender rule is here.

I'm not a native English speaker and I have limited education in English, although I speak and understand it fluently.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a case of any gender requirement for these activities.

English has no gender-neutral pronouns so the choice to use "her" is simply a statement made by the author that they recognize that these activities are **not specifically male-oriented**.

It is an act of political correctness to deliberately use "her" on some occassions when the gender of the actor is not known or relevant.

Answer (score 1):

English has traditionally used the third person plural pronoun *they* for indeterminate gender. But a few hundred years ago, a grammar book argued that *they* is illogical because it's plural. The book suggested using *he* instead. Some people took up this advice and started using *he*, but it makes no sense either in some contexts (e.g., *When the purchaser uses the razor to shave his legs...*). Some people, have begun to use *she,* sometimes in alternation with *he,* to show concern for non-sexist language. Other people continue to use *they.*

Comment: That seems reasonable. So its not limited to my topic (Design and Game studies) but can be found in other types of literature?

Comment: Yes, you find it here and there, particularly in academic writing.