# She/he to refer a user

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, grammatical-gender, singular-they, generic-they

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reason for the current trend to use «she» as the gender-neutral pronoun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28508/reason-for-the-current-trend-to-use-she-as-the-gender-neutral-pronoun)
>   [Can the feminine pronouns be gender-neutral?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51948/can-the-feminine-pronouns-be-gender-neutral)
>   [Is there a correct gender-neutral, singular pronoun (“his” versus “her” versus “their”)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus)

Programmer here. I am confused with the usage of the term "She/he" when referring a prementioned and undefined user. Below is a sentence found from MSDN magazine:

"When the user decides to create a new customer, **she** must fill in the data entry form in Figure 2."

I myself use the term "She/he" is this context, since without mentioning both can be regarded as gender discrimination, and placing 'she' before 'he' is respecting the ladies.

So, can I just use 'She' in this context, that will save some typing.

Comment: Don’t use *she/he*, and don’t use *she* unless you know the antecedent is **guaranteed** to be female, like with pregnant mothers.  Use *they* like everybody else does, or *he* if it is a distinct male or you just cannot help yourself.  You’d best check your spelling of **refering*, too; we don’t need anymore `HTTP_REFERER` fiascos.

Comment: Spelling corrected.

Comment: I do use **they** when talking about 'users'， it is just that it is talking about only one user: When **a user decides**..., is using 'they' still syntactically acceptable?

Comment: Yes, it is syntactically acceptable, but whether it is politically acceptable is another matter altogether. See [nohat’s answer here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/55/2085) for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people, until recently, preferred the use of masculine pronoun. But with the rise of female writers, feminist literatures, and feminist movements, the trend has changed dramatically, with many writers inclined toward the use of feminine gender.

That said, the use of *he/she* is a bit awkward and is better avoided. From the other two, it doesn't matter which one to choose as long as you are consistent.

Comment: Actually, *he/she* is not only obscenely awkward, it does not occur in speech at all, so is useless.  The problem with using *she* is that doing so makes people think that you are talking about a specific female, but you aren’t.  The reason not to use *he*, if you follow that line of thinking, is that does this now makes people think you are talking about a specific male, but you still aren’t. Dunno that this is due to femininism though.  Someone using the very popular singular *they* does so to intentionally make it nonspecific, somebody they don’t know and you don’t either.

Comment: I agree he/she is just annoying and awkward.  I have seen, as Noah has suggested, many instances of authors especially when referring to people of a particular profession (like engineers and programmers) that have been traditionally dominated by males as 'she' as if to say, "See, I am giving equal opportunity to women here".

Comment: @tchrist You probably don't use _℅_ in speech too, but that doesn't make it useless.

Comment: I say "he or she" all the time, but I say it quickly, as if it's only one word.  So the best way to write what I say is probably "he/she".

Comment: @DavidWallace: Could be, but most writers don't use that combination. I am sure there's nothing wrong with it, but it definitely is rather overly descriptive and a bit awkward.

Answer (score 2):

I have observed a tendency in technical communications to alternate between using 'she' and 'he'.  It is even suggested (though not necessarily recommended) in [this article](http://www.herodios.com/pronouns.html) and [this other one](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/styleforstudents/c1_p15.html) as a solution to "The Pronoun Problem":

> For example, always use he/him/his in odd numbered chapters, and always use she/her/hers in even numbered chapters. This strategy does promote balance and has sometimes been used to good effect in textbooks, but it doesn't solve the real problem of distracting the reader.

Personally I find it very distracting, and also a bit silly.

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus) has some other answers about addressing "The Pronoun Problem" with other gender-neutral alternatives.

Comment: + 1. I too find it distracting because it is so obviously an attempt to get around a problem that isn't a problem at all if you use 'they'. We all use 'you', as I have just done, when we don't specifically mean the person we are addressing, and no one seems bothered about that. For a thorough discussion of singular 'they', see: http://www.crossmyt.com/hc/linghebr/austheir.html

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding filler helps avoid this problem. Your example sentence could be more to the point, like this, "To create a customer [record] the user completes form xyz."