# When I'm referencing a undefined person, when should I use "she" or "he"?

Tags: word-usage, pronouns, formality, feminine

This is something I realized in some text I read (books and articles), I don't identify it when speaking to people. When a pronoun is used replacing an undefined person sometimes "he" is used (I would say most of the time) and others "she" is used. Like in the sentence "The user is very clever, she found an error.", in formal Portuguese writing the pronouns for undefined person are always masculin, is it optional for English?

Comment: [Use **they**, it's the gender-neutral pronoun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-vs-her-vs-their/55#55)

Comment: See also [She/he to refer a user](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78886/she-he-to-refer-a-user?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is more common to use masculine pronoun, ie **he**, to refer to a person whose gender is not indicated. Feminine pronouns are more used for countries, cities, ocean liners, etc. It's also acceptable to say: *Someone...their/they/them...* or *Someone...his or her/(s)he/him or her...*

Comment: So you're saying that it is optional, right?

Comment: Yeah sure, it is optional.